# ML.NET: Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features'

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm trying to learn ML.NET/Get into Machine Learning, but I'm stuck at an issue.

My goal is to create a Trained Model that can be used to predict a city based on input.

**This code:**

```cs
var dataPath = "cities.csv";
var mlContext = new MLContext();
var loader = mlContext.Data.CreateTextLoader<CityData>(hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ',');

var data = loader.Load(dataPath);

string featuresColumnName = "Features";

var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "PostalCode", "CityName")
        .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, clustersCount: 3));

var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
```

Which should take an CSV as input (Which contains a list of Cities (Column 0 = Postal Code, Column 1 = CityName), and then add these features to the pipeline, gives the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features': expected Vector<R4>, got Vector<Text>
```

On the "Fit"- function.

I've done a bit of digging on the GitHub Repo, but I can't seem to find a solution. I'm working from the Iris- example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/iris-clustering) (Of course with my modifications)

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `CityName` is a text column. Try doing a `OneHotEncode` transform on it and passing that into the `Concatenate` transform.

Comment: I think @Jon is right, you need to categorize (similar to keras.to_categorical) your text features. Something like this : mlContext.Transforms.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "Feature1", inputColumnName:"TextFeature"))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "Feature1", ... ))

Comment: @jgoday Could you possibly create an example from my current pipeline code? It doens't seem like you can start with an "Append" for the Pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using FeaturizeText to transform strings features into a float array ones

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms
    .Text.FeaturizeText("PostalCodeF", "PostalCode")
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("CityNameF", "CityName"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(featuresColumnName, "PostalCodeF", "CityNameF"))
    .Append(mlContext.Clustering.Trainers.KMeans(featuresColumnName, clustersCount: 3));

var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
```

Comment: this solution worked for me as well but sometimes I receive this error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Schema mismatch for input column 'ACCOUNT_CharExtractor': expected Expected Single or known-size vector of Single, got Vector<Single>
Arg_ParamName_Name"

Comment: any suggestions please ?

Comment: @EmnaJaoua Can you provide a minimal example to test it ?

Comment: I apologize I had a problem with the input data. it didn't had the column ACCOUNT on it, that's why I received this error.